Eigenstructure of (Symmetric Block-Circulant) Covariance Matrix from Modular Arithmetic
I'm trying to understand the eigenvalues of a particular block-circulant matrix $\Sigma$.
I'm studying modular arithmetic, specifically $x + y \pmod p$. I call $p$ the "modulus" or the "order". I construct a matrix $Y_p \in \{0, 1\}^{p^2 \times p}$ where each row of $Y_p$ is a one-hot vector of $x+y \pmod p$ where $x, y \in \{0, 1, ..., p-1\}$. I then define:
$$\Sigma_p := Y_p \; Y_p^T \in \{0, 1\}^{p^2 \times p^2}$$
I've attached numerical visualizations of $Y_p$ and $\Sigma_p$ below for $p=7$ (although I'm not specifically interested in prime $p$). My questions are:

To confirm, $\Sigma_p$ is a block-circulant matrix, yes?

What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\Sigma_p$? I can answer this numerically, but I'd like an analytical characterization if possible. Numerically, it seems like there are $p$ non-zero eigenvalues all of value $p$.

Here, I'm considering modular addition i.e. $x + y \pmod p$. What polynomials of $x, y$ will ensure $\Sigma_p$ remains a block-circulant matrix? For those polynomials, is an analytical characterization of the eigenvalues & eigenvectors pf $\Sigma_p$ possible?


$Y_{p=7}$ (white values denote 1, black values denote 0):

$\Sigma_{p=7}$  (white values denote 1, black values denote 0):

Here are two ways to generate $Y_p$ in Python:
import numpy as np


p = 7
Y_p = np.zeros((p**2, p))

# Populate Y_p_correct by setting the (x+y) mod p entry to 1 for each pair (x, y)
for x in range(p):
    for y in range(p):
        # The index for rows is a flattened index for matrix coordinates (x, y)
        row_index = x * p + y
        # The column index is the modular sum
        col_index = (x + y) % p
        Y_p[row_index, col_index] = 1

sigma_p = Y_p @ Y_p.T


Yes, this appears to be block-circulant. I'm not sure how to read this matrix; are the white boxes ones or zeros?

Note that the non-zero eigenvalues of $Y_pY_p^T$ are the same as those of the smaller matrix $Y_p^TY_p$

@BenGrossmann whites are 1s, blacks are 0s. My apologies for not including a legend!

This question is treated with a broad view in an article by Sergej Rjasanow with title "Effective Algorithms with Circulant Block Matrices" which is available through "Science Direct".

@RylanSchaeffer One observation you might find interesting: $Y_p$ will have always have orthogonal columns due to your one-hot encoding scheme. It follows that $Y_p^TY_p$ will be diagonal, with diagonal entries equal to the non-zero eigenvalues of $Y_pY_p^T$. Also, the sum of the eigenvalues of $Y_pY_p^T$ will always be $p^2$.

@RylanSchaeffer Notably, $Y_pY_p^T$ will necessarily have the same repeated, non-zero eigenvalue of $p$ if the polynomial $f(x,y)$ that you're using is such that $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is invertible for every $x$. There are other situations where this would occur though, such as with the polynomial $f(x) = x$.

Let $M$ denote the $p \times p$ permutation matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&1\\
&0&1\\
&&\ddots & \ddots\\
&&&0&1\\
1&&&&0}.
$$
Your martrix $Y_p$ can be written as
$$
Y_p = \pmatrix{I\\ M \\ M^2\\ \vdots \\ M^{p-1}}.
$$
Note that $Y_p$ has full column-rank, i.e. $\text{rank}(Y_p) = p$. As such, the eigenspace of $Y_pY_p^T$ associated with $0$ will have dimension $p^2 - p$. The eigenvalues of $Y_p^TY_p$ will all be non-zero, and the matrices $Y_p^TY_p$ and $Y_pY_p^T$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues.
Now, note that the columns of $Y_p$ are mutually orthogonal, each with $p$ non-zero entries. It follows that $Y_p^TY_p = pI$. This can also be confirmed with the block-matrix computation
$$
Y_p^TY_p = II + M^TM + M^{2T}M^2 + \cdots = I + I + I + \cdots = pI.
$$
In any case, we conclude, $Y_p^TY_p$ has $p$ as its only eigenvalue, with multiplicity $p$. So, the eigenvalues of $Y_pY_p^T$ are $0$ with multiplicity $p^2 - p$ and $p$ with multiplicity $p$.

To reframe this, the matrix $\frac 1{\sqrt p}Y_p$ has orthonormal rows. It follows that $(\frac 1{\sqrt p}Y_p)(\frac 1{\sqrt p}Y_p)^T = \frac 1p Y_pY_p^T$ is a projection matrix, which means that it has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$ with mutually orthogonal eigenspaces.

This is awesome - thank you! Is it also possible to characterize the eigenvectors of $\Sigma_p$?

@RylanSchaeffer Yes, looks like I forgot to write my answer to that effect... the eigenspace associated with $p$ is just the range (AKA column space) of $Y_p$ (i.e. you could take the columns of $Y_p$ as the associated basis), and the eigenspace associated with $0$ is just the orthogonal complement to the range, or equivalently the nullspace of $Y_p^T$. If you want specific eigenvectors to form a basis, numpy and matlab both have nullspace functions of some kind that can be used to that effect.

@RylanSchaeffer Also, I finally understood how the block matrix corresponds to $x + y$. For arbitrary polynomials, we could always block-diagonalize the resulting matrix encoding the operation which makes finding eigenvalues significantly easier, but I don't think we'll always get an analytical formula

My hope is that because $\Sigma_p$ is block-circulant (I think), there might be some way to characterize its eigenvectors exactly using the discrete Fourier transform, Kronecker products and maybe some other ingredients? At least for $x + y \pmod p$, if not for other polynomials

@RylanSchaeffer You already have an answer for $x+y$

@Ryan Actually, I'm a bit confused. It looks like the block matrix that you gave us is the operation table for $y - x$, isn't it? Otherwise, why are the diagonal blocks the same? Perhaps I misunderstood how this matrix is supposed to correspond to the polynomial

I'm not sure how I already have an answer for the eigen_vectors_ of $\Sigma_p$? What am I missing?

I added Python code to show how $Y_p$ is constructed.

Please see the article I mentionned in a comment to Rylan.

@RylanSchaeffer My first comment on my answer tells you what the eigenspaces of $\Sigma_p$ are. Using that, you could get a basis of eigenvectors as I explain in my comment

@Ryan and the construction makes sense now, thank you
